# angular 2 how to access a json returned in the template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

i have a service that return data from the database.
in the OnInit i call the service and pass it the parameter and get back the results:

```
    this._route.params
  .map(params => params['id'])
  .subscribe((id) => {
    this.title = id ? "Edit User" : "New User";
    if (!id) {
      return;
    }
    //console.log(id);
    this._locationService.getLocation(id)
      .subscribe(
          location => this.location = location,
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log( "finished"  )
        );
  });
```

and in the template i see the results like so:

```
Location - {{location | json}}
```

and the result i see is:
Location - [ { "id": "1", "name": "shliz coffee", "address": "hel st 36,TA", "lat": "32.060143", "lng": "34.770557" } ]

all good right?
well, when i try:
{{location.name}}

i get this error: EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

why can't i access the data?

i am not sure if and how it is connected but when i log this.location in the constructor i get undefined while in the oninit i log this.location i get the object.
anyone have any idea what is wrong?

so just for test, i initialize the location variable like so:

```
location:Location = {
  name: 'some name',
  address: 'some addredd',
  lat: '45.74837',
  lng: '32.98575'
};
```

and tried, and still couldn't access it in the template. so i commented the oninit part of calling the service and database, and then i do get access to my initialized values.

but it is bizzare since i log the this.location in the complete subscribe method and it is there, and as we know in the template when i use the json pipe it show it.

i'm lost

Comment: Look at the JSON again.  Set a global variable to the result and play around with it in the console (`window['test'] = location`) or set a breakpoint to inspect the actual value you're setting.  Check `typeof test` in the console.  You should see why `location.name` will never be defined.  Also check out the answer from @micronyks, Angular 2 isn't silent about trying to bind to properties of an undefined variable before an async operation returns.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Elvis operator (?.)` as shown here,

```
{{location?.name}}
```

The reason of error is, you want to show data before it arrives to the view using `async` call.

read a small explanation. http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0

Comment: using the elvis operator just doesn't show the error, but no change.
if i log in the subscribe:
() => console.log( typeof this.location  )
 i get: object

Comment: This should work for sure. Try to write `.subscribe((data)=>{this.location=data; console.log(this.location);},error....);`

Comment: again, in the console i do get the object with everything correctly inside. but when on the template there is {{location.name}} i get: XCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Go with elvis operator. `?.` As answered and shown.

Comment: but it doesn't output the name.